# I'm making a temperature converter app, but there's something I don't understand

Tags: python, math

I am making a temperature translation application, but there are some points that I do not understand. What operator do I need to use when converting kelvin to fahrenheit?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR3uu.png)

I set the kelvin value to 273.15 and the degree value I got from the information I received from the user

Comment: What mathematical formula would you use to convert Kelvin to Fahrenheit?

Comment: I used the + operator in other translation operations, I don't know which one to use in this one :(

Comment: Unclear how this is a Python question. If you lookup the formula, what operators does it use?

Answer (score 0):

> What operator do I need to use when converting kelvin to fahrenheit

This is the formula

> °F =(K - 273.15)* 1.8000+ 32.00

You already have `K`. Those operators shown are the same in Python